# How to make a box plot of adjusted means from negative binomial model

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How would you make a box plot of the adjusted, rather than raw, means (with CI) between two protocols for a model I made using the `glm.nb()` function in `R`.

For example (tolerate weight not being a count for examples sake here):

```
library(MASS)
summary(glm.nb(formula = weight ~ 1 + Diet + Time, subset = levels(Chick) == "1", data = ChickWeight))
```

So for Chick 1, by default there's a mean comparison between Diet 1 vs. Diet 2; Diet 1 vs. Diet 3; Diet 1 vs. Diet 4, and time is an additional predictor that is adjusting the means being compared as the chick gets older.

If I want to get those adjusted means from R instead of using the raw means with tapply or something:

```
with(data = subset(x = ChickWeight, subset = levels(Chick) == "1"),
     expr = tapply(X = weight, INDEX = Diet, FUN = mean))
```

I want to end up with something similar to this:

```
ggplot(data = subset(x = ChickWeight, subset = levels(Chick) == "1"),
       mapping = aes(x = Diet, y = weight)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: I have some questions about what you're trying to do.  (1) I think your subsetting isn't working the way you think it is. If you do `subset = (Chick=="1")` (which is what I think you meant), you won't be able to fit Diet as a predictor, because each chick only gets one diet.  In general to get adjusted means you can use `predict`, or the `lsmeans` package ... (2) what should the multiple points per Diet be?  One point per chick?  Do I assume that you want the points for chicks standardized by time?

Comment: @BenBolker, (1) you're right, I incorrectly thought that Chick 1 was receiving both diets. I tried lsmeans and didn't get it, maybe I should make another question with simple two group dummy data for an example. Let's try the following (each row is an individual): `x <- data.frame(y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9 , 10, 12, 13), binary = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))`   Here's the raw means `tapply(X = x$y, INDEX = x$binary, FUN = mean)` I think I want something like the adjusted means that `summary(lm(formula = y ~ 1 + binary + time, data = x))` is using.

Comment: I think I had issues using `lsmeans` with `glm.nb()`

Comment: `x <- data.frame(y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9 , 10, 12, 13), binary = factor(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))` with `library(lsmeans)` and `summary(ref.grid(lm(formula = y ~ 1 + binary + time, data = x)))` means that `lsmeans(object = ref.grid(lm(formula = y ~ 1 + binary + time, data = x)), specs = "binary")` would give me the adjusted means, if I understand the function correctly.

Comment: I figured out what my problem was, I was using the `vglm(family = posnegbinomial())` from the `VGAM` package. So, @BenBolker, would you show me how I could use the prediction method you mentioned rather than `lsmeans()` and I'll mark that as the correct answer?